# Datetime.strptime format for 2022-08-24T04:57:17.065000+00:00

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format, iso8601

We have the following string in a variable:

```
date_variable = "2022-08-24T04:57:17.065000+00:00"
```

We would like to convert this to datetime.

The following does not work:

```
timestamp_formatted = datetime.strptime(date_variable, '%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S.%f+%z')
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You left out the `T` and `%z` includes the sign of the time zone offset so remove the `+`:

```py
from datetime import datetime

date_variable = "2022-08-24T04:57:17.065000+00:00"
#                          ^

timestamp_formatted = datetime.strptime(date_variable, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')
print(repr(timestamp_formatted))
```

Output:

```
datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 24, 4, 57, 17, 65000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Comment: Yes but doesn’t explain what was incorrect about the OP code.